# Adding View in xml layout android 2.2+

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-support-library

I use this code in order to adding a line between my GUI componenets

```
  <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#3f9fe0"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/titleOfSection"
        android:id="@+id/sectionLine"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
```

but it seemst that `View` is supporting from android api level 14+. I am using support library so it is possible to change this code in a way that android 2.2+ support the `View` too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrong, Views was created since api 1 as stated in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/view.html).

I just tried your code with a minimum of 1 and maximum of 8 and it still works maybe you are referring to a different View, because if View does not exist since api 1 then buttons, TextView, etc wont exist as well because they inherits from View.

Comment: Ow, I am sorry. It was GridView not view. My bad. Any way you answer is correct for this question. Thanks for your attention Rob

Comment: @HuseinBehbudiRad you are welcome, its rod hahaha, +1 this post as well thank you.. :))

Comment: It is about 1 AM in my time.It seems that yy eyes not working right :d